# Bind data from SQL to the objects with have the reference to another class

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following class:

```
    public class Student : StudentInfo
    {
        public School School { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class School
    {
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }

        public string SchoolAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class StudentInfo
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public string StudentAge { get; set; }

        public string StudentGender { get; set; }

        public Relationship StudentRelationship { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Relationship
    {
        public string StudentMotherName { get; set; }

        public string StudentFatherName { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have the following SQL query that return all necessary data and ready to be bind into the classes above, I am doing it like the following:

```
    private List<Student> StudentList()
    {
        var students = new List<Student>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = "SELECT a.[StudentName], a.[StudentAge], a.[StudentGender], a.[StudentMotherName], a.[StudentFatherName], b.[SchoolName], b.[SchoolAddress]
FROM [Student] a WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN [School] b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.[StudentID] = b.[StudentID]";

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        students.Add
                        (
                            new Student
                            {
                                StudentName = reader["StudentName"].ToString(),
                                StudentAge = reader["StudentAge"].ToString(),
                                StudentGender = reader["StudentGender"].ToString()
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return students;
    }
```

I am confused on how to bind the objects into **StudentInfo** and **School** and **Relationship** class, since I am just instantiate the Student class.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't Student class extending StudentInfo? Or why are you extending School and also holding a School field?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, I should inherit from a StudentInfo class instead and as it is already inherited from StudentInfo class, so it shouldn't be need for StudentInfo field to be at Student class anymore?

Comment: I just don't understand why you need abstract classes or inheritance. A Student can hold all the info fields itself + a School and Relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two other objects to build a student

Follow a pattern like this

```
while (reader.Read()) {
    // initialize temp objects for each row 
    var s = new Student();
    var rel = new Relationship();
    var school = new School();

    // Extract database values
    s.StudentName = reader["StudentName"].ToString();
    s.StudentAge = reader["StudentAge"].ToString();
    s.StudentGender = reader["StudentGender"].ToString();
    // TODO: load other variables 

    // add object to list 
    students.Add(s);
 }
```

(keeping in mind you can't make a new abstract class)

I would suggest checking out if any ORM library fits into your development needs, though

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, for the new instance of Student, there are no parameters. I should make it like this? `public Student(StudentInfo si, School school) { si = new StudentInfo(); school = new School(); }` ? Thanks

Comment: With that constructor, you are overwriting the parameters, so that's not quite correct. You would need something like `this.si = si; this.school = school`. Or you can make `var st = new Student();` then `st.StudentInfo = si;` within the loop

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @cricket_007 should be enough for your case but it seems like you are not familiar to ORM. So I would add few more details to it -

**Firstly**, you can run the raw SQL yourself and create the object graph yourself. The example is already given in the answer.

**Secondly**, If you need to mix both by running the raw SQL yourself but does not want to generate the object graph or map yourself. You can use **Dapper**. Here is a simple example for dapper - http://dapper-tutorial.net/

**Thirdly**, If you want complete object mapping and does not want to write the raw SQL yourself, try entityframework or NHibernate (very old, EF is more recent). Links are -

EF : http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx

NHibernate: http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application